# Creating a new object outside a loop that requires a string

Tags: java, loops

I have an object that requires a string; however, I need to initiate this object outside of a loop, in such a way that a new instance is not created every time the loop reiterates. But at the same time I need the string that the loop generates to be put into the object. How can I achieve this? Here is an example of what I am trying to do :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (file)
String word = "";
While (input.hasNext()){
word = input.next()
object myObject = new object(word) // this is what I want to put outside the loop using the object 'word'
}
```

Comment: So which word should be used to create the object?  The first one in the input?  The last one?

Comment: you want to put all the strings (in loop) into your object ?

Comment: word (a string) should be used to create the object

Comment: @coder I want to put the string 'word' into my object, the object is already set to take in a string.

Comment: yes but, as you are in a while loop, word (a string) will keep on changing

Comment: @AlfredoSequeida Each iteration in the loop has its own `word`. If your object is outside the loop, it can have only one word. *Which word* should it have?

Comment: @khelwood it should have the word taken from input.next(). The program reads strings from a file and then I want the current string to be put into the object.

Comment: You're calling `input.next()` multiple times, and getting a different value of `word` each time.  Which one of those values should be used, if you only want one object?

Comment: sorry , I figured out what my problem was, I actually did want multiple objects. I was thinking it was causing a logical error, but its not. Thank you to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only need a single instance of your `object` class, use a setter to change the word inside the loop :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (file)
String word = "";
object myObject = new object(word);
while (input.hasNext()){
  word = input.next()
  myObject.setWord(word);
}
```

I'm assuming there is more logic in your actual loop, which does something with `myObject`. Otherwise, there's no point in calling `setWord`.

Comment: im sorry, I dont get why I would use a setter, i am trying to get word (from insde the loop) and then use it outside the loop. And yes, there is more logic to it, the reason why I i dont want it to stay inside the loop is because each time my loop header evaluates to true, a new object is created, but I just want the object to be created once.

Comment: @AlfredoSequeida In each iteration of the loop you assign a new value to `word`. Which one of these values do you expect your `object` to contain when you exist the loop? And if you don't want to create the object in each iteration of the loop, you must create it before the loop, which means the only way to pass the `word` to it inside the loop is via a setter method.